# Go to bottom most directory?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I'm working with a directory with a lot of nested folders like /path/to/project/users/me/tutorial

I found a neat way to navigate up the folders here:
https://superuser.com/questions/449687/using-cd-to-go-up-multiple-directory-levels

But I'm wondering how to go down them. This seems significantly more difficult, but a couple things about the directory structure help. Each directory only has another directory in it, or maybe a directory and a README.

The directory I'm looking for looks more like a traditional project and might have random directories and files in it (more than any of the other higher directories certainly).

Right now I'm working on a solution using uh.. recursive bash functions cd'ing into the only directory underneath until there are either 0 or 2+ directories to loop through. This doesn't work yet..

Am I overcomplicating this? I feel like there could be some sweet solution    using find. Ideally I want to be able to type something like:

```
down path
```

where path is a top-level folder. And that will take me down to the bottom folder tutorial.

Comment: Use `find . -type d` and go to the one with most slashes in it - by passing to `awk` with the field separator set to slash and counting the number of fields.

Comment: You can take advantage of `CDPATH` if your directories are uniquely named. If there are non-unique names, the command will go to the first occurrence of the name. Example: `export CDPATH=/path/to/project/users/me:/path/to/project/users/her:/path/to/project/users/him`. Any commands such as `cd tutorial` will search the current path, then the `CDPATH`. So if you are in `/tmp` it will jump to `/path/to/project/users/me/tutorial`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My attempt - this actually works now! I'm still afraid it could easily go infinite with symbolic links or some such.

Also, I have to run this like 
`. down`
from within the first empty folder.

```
#!/bin/bash
function GoDownOnce {
  Dirs=$(find ./ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d)
  NumDirs=$(echo $Dirs | wc -w)
  echo $Dirs
  echo $NumDirs
  if [ "$NumDirs" = "1" ]; then
      cd $Dirs
          GoDownOnce
  fi
}
GoDownOnce
```

Comment: This doesn't work perfectly.. but why did so many people delete their answers?? I think other answers were probably good too (or at least as good as my answer).

Answer (score 1):

There is an environment variable named `CDPATH`. This variable is used by `cd` in the same manner that executables use `PATH` when searching for pathname.

For example, if you have the following directories:

```
/path/to/project/users/me
/path/to/project/users/me/tutorial
/path/to/project/users/him
/path/to/project/users/him/test
/path/to/project/users/her
/path/to/project/users/her/uat
/path/to/project/users/her/dev
/path/to/application
/path/to/application/conf
/path/to/application/bin
/path/to/application/share

export CDPATH=/path/to/project/users/me:/path/to/project/users/him:/path/to/project/users/her:/path/to/application
```

A simple command such as `cd tutorial` will search the above paths for `tutorial`.

Let's pretend `/path/to/application` has directories underneath namely, `conf`, `bin`, `share`. A simple `cd conf` will send you to `/path/to/application/conf` as long as none of the paths before it have `conf` directory. This behavior is similar to executables in `PATH`. The first occurrence always gets chosen

Answer (score 0):

A friend also suggested this sweet one liner:

```
cd $(find . -type d -name tutorial)
```

Admittedly this isn't quite what I asked, but it gets the job done pretty well.